# Where to extract downloaded System Image File of android to run in android emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, android-emulator, android-12

I wanted to run android 12 in android studio emulator.
When I started downloading the system image file from android studio, due to some network issues it failed many times. So I thought to download the system image file manually from this link [`https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-windows_x64-8807927.zip`](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-windows_x64-8807927.zip) that was shown in android studio when I tried to download the system image file before. Now I have downloaded the system image file manually but I don't know that where I have to extract it. First I tried extracting it on `/Users/USERNAME/Library/Android/sdk` but it didn't worked. So please tell me the location to extract the files. I will be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should unzip it and let it lie where it is. Then go to your device settings and change your emulator's system image to S(android 12). That is what worked for me.